# haystack elasticsearch facet but disregard filters on this query

Tags: elasticsearch

Using haystack solr I can do this:

```
# facet by category but disregard any category filters on this query
squeryset = squeryset.facet('{!ex=category}category')
```

which will give me facets for the category but ignore any category filters

Now how do I do the same query using elasticsearch?

It's for when someone queries for something with a specific category, I can show the counts for the other categories they did not select.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. See http://demo.fullscale.co/multiselect/ for a working demo to do this in ES. It is however not supported by Haystack. I'm working on that to make it work.
Paul

Comment: Hi Paul, did you make any progress on making this work for ES? We are looking for something similar

Comment: Hi @PaulBormans im looking for similar solution. please can you post the solution here.

Comment: I should write a blog on this subject and post the link here... give me some time to do this.
Paul

Comment: Please see http://paulbormans.blogspot.nl/p/multi-select-faceting-with-django.html for a write-up of the solution that is working for me with the source code.